# MySQL determining column types basing on a result set

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a stored procedure or just a complex `SELECT` statement. I would like to know *what are the types of returned columns*. Is it possible in MySQL, or I have to use some programmatic access and read the result values from there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the type of a column you can use the `SHOW COLUMNS` statement.
Have a look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html

Comment: As I understand correctly `SHOW COLUMNS` only work on tables and views, so the only way to do it would be to create artificial view based on `SELECT` and check the types. I am rather looking for some straightforward solution (if one exists).